# One dropdown field leading to updated values for another dropdown field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have two drop downs, when **dropdown-1** is changed, selected option of **dropdown-2** should be changed to the same as **dropdown-1**

Dropdown-1:

```
<div className="select-style-right joiner-select">
    <select className="selectalljoiners" onChange={this.handleMainSelectChanged} value={this.state.selectedJoinerValue}>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
        <option value="Probationary">Probationary</option>
        <option value="Contractual">Contractual</option>
        <option value="Intern">Intern</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Dropdown-2:

```
<div className="select-style-right joiner-select">
    <select className={index} value={this.state.selectedJoinerValue}>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
        <option value="Probationary">Probationary</option>
        <option value="Contractual">Contractual</option>
        <option value="Intern">Intern</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**handleMainSelectChanged:**

```
handleMainSelectChanged = (e) => {
        thisclass.setState({
            selectedJoinerValue: e.target.value
        })
}
```

New to React, don't know how to achieve this. Please help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of dropdowns changed the second one will take same selected option.

https://jsfiddle.net/b1atetou/

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { value: "" }
    }

    handleDropDownChage = (event) => {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <div>
                    <select onChange={this.handleDropDownChage} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
                        <option value="Probationary">Probationary</option>
                        <option value="Contractual">Contractual</option>
                        <option value="Intern">Intern</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <select onChange={this.handleDropDownChage} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
                        <option value="Probationary">Probationary</option>
                        <option value="Contractual">Contractual</option>
                        <option value="Intern">Intern</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay great that is working in fiddle, same as i want. Then i implemented into my component, i did not worked. Than i created another fiddle with the same code of your's. It's giving me errors.
https://jsfiddle.net/uxz28mff/1/

Comment: Switch language from `JavaScript` to `BABEL + JSX`. It will solve your problem with jsfiddle